# Video support on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, video, pjsip

I have successfull built the libyuv.a library but when i run configure-iPhone(https://code.google.com/p/siphon/wiki/VIdeoSupport) 
and i get the logs which tells libyuv not available and video support disabled.
Can anyone please tell me how do i link the libyuv.a file to configure-iPhone

```
logs :

checking for libyuv installations...
Using libyuv prefix... /Users/sandeep_sr/Desktop/pjp_1811/iOS/video/iOS
checking libyuv.h usability... no
checking libyuv.h presence... no
checking for libyuv.h... no
checking for InitCpuFlags in -lyuv... yes
Checking if libyuv library is available... no
libyuv library not found, video support disabled
Checking if small filter is disabled... no
Checking if large filter is disabled... no
Checking if Speex AEC is disabled...no
Checking if G.711 codec is disabled...no
Checking if L16 codec is disabled...no
Checking if GSM codec is disabled...no
Checking if G.722 codec is disabled...no
Checking if G.722.1 codec is disabled...no
Checking if Speex codec is disabled...no
Checking if iLBC codec is disabled...no
Skipping libsamplerate detection
Building libresample as shared library... no
Checking if SDL is disabled... yes
Using ffmpeg prefix... /Users/sandeep_sr/Desktop/pjp_1811/iOS/video/iOS
checking for pkg-config... pkg-config
checking ffmpeg packages...  libavformat libavcodec libswscale libavutil
checking for v4l2_open in -lv4l2... no
Skipping Intel IPP settings (not wanted)
Checking if SSL support is disabled... yes
Checking if OpenCORE AMR support is disabled... yes
Checking if SILK support is disabled... yes
checking if select() needs correct nfds... no (default)
** Decided that select() doesn't need correct nfds (please check)
checking if pj_thread_create() should enforce stack size... no (default)
checking if pj_thread_create() should allocate stack... no (default)
** Setting non-blocking recv() retval to EAGAIN (please check)
** Setting non-blocking connect() retval to EINPROGRESS (please check)
aconfigure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating build.mak
config.status: creating build/os-auto.mak
config.status: creating build/cc-auto.mak
config.status: creating pjlib/build/os-auto.mak
config.status: creating pjlib-util/build/os-auto.mak
config.status: creating pjmedia/build/os-auto.mak
config.status: creating pjsip/build/os-auto.mak
config.status: creating third_party/build/os-auto.mak
config.status: creating third_party/build/portaudio/os-auto.mak
config.status: creating pjlib/include/pj/compat/os_auto.h
config.status: pjlib/include/pj/compat/os_auto.h is unchanged
config.status: creating pjlib/include/pj/compat/m_auto.h
config.status: pjlib/include/pj/compat/m_auto.h is unchanged
config.status: creating pjmedia/include/pjmedia/config_auto.h
config.status: pjmedia/include/pjmedia/config_auto.h is unchanged
config.status: creating pjmedia/include/pjmedia-codec/config_auto.h
config.status: pjmedia/include/pjmedia-codec/config_auto.h is unchanged
config.status: creating pjsip/include/pjsip/sip_autoconf.h
config.status: pjsip/include/pjsip/sip_autoconf.h is unchanged


Configurations for current target have been written to 'build.mak', and 'os-auto.mak' in various build directories, and pjlib/include/pj/compat/os_auto.h.

Further customizations can be put in:
  - 'user.mak'
  - 'pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h'

The next step now is to run 'make dep' and 'make'.

Done configuring for iPhoneOS6.1.sdk

Sandeeps-Mac-mini-2:pjproject-2.1.0 sandeep_sr$
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you building libyuv yourself?  If so, I ran into this problem also and had to do:

`ln -s /usr/local/include/libyuv/libyuv /usr/local/include/libyuv/libyuv/`

or to wherever you installed libyuv.

Hope that helps, if you're still trying to get this working.